# how to avoid sub query or how can i save time

Tags: php, mysql, loops, sum, subquery

hi i am edited my question

there is 4 table

### team

### id | teamname |

1  | lal

2  | sobuj

### member

id | membername| team |

1 | sagor| 1 |

2 | sumon| 1 |

### dps

### id | member| team | deposit | refund | ddate

1 | 1 | 1 | 100 | 12 | 2016-09-01 |

2 | 2 | 1 | 120 | 34 | 2016-09-01 |

3 | 1 | 1 | 130 | 22 | 2016-09-01 |

4 | 3 | 1 | 120 | 0  | 2016-09-01 |

and

### mvs

### id | member| team | mvs_total| refund | ddate

1 | 1 | 1 | 100 | 12 | 2016-09-01 |

2 | 2 | 1 | 120 | 34 | 2016-09-01 |

3 | 1 | 1 | 130 | 22 | 2016-09-01 |

### 4 | 3 | 1 | 120 | 0  | 2016-09-01 |

### here is my query

```
$result=mysql_query(select * from member where team='1');
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
do{

$aresult=mysql_query(select sum(deposit)-sum(refund)as balance from dps where member='$row[id]');
$arow=mysql_fetch_array($aresult);
echo $arow[balance];

$bresult=mysql_query(select sum(mvs_total)as mvs_balance from mvs where member='$row[id]' and date1<='2016-09-01');
$brow=mysql_fetch_array($bresult);

}while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

its taking too much time
how to avoid sub query or how can i save time
advice plz 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select sum(deposit)-sum(refund) from dps JOIN member ON (dps. member = member.id) WHERE team='1';
```

Comment: hi krish your solution was right but i have edited my questing with one more table please look at it if possible